# Regex - for books, contain "NAME-NAME" but split " - "

Tags: regex

I'm trying to sort my ebooks but I'm running into a problem where the name of the author contains a - but I use it to split it into writer - title. Any suggestions on how to create a group(?) that says it can not be " - " but it can be "\w-\w"

```
^(\[([a-zA-Z0-9 ,&]+)\] ?)?((?P<writer>([^\-_0-9]+)(?=\s*-\s*)(?!\s*-\s*[0-9.]+)|\b))( \s*-\s* )(\[(?P<serie>[a-zA-Z0-9 ,'&]+[^\s0-9.]{1,}?)(?=\s*)?(-?\s?)?(\#\s?)??(?P<serie_index>[0-9.]+)\](\s*-\s*)?)?(\s)?(?P<title>[a-zA-Z0-9 .,'&]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/21Jsy0WrQS9XmWov)

-- EDIT -- 
One more problem popped up, if a serie name has a number in it, how do I split it on the last number?

```
Simon, Will - [kamer 11901] Moord in Eldorado
Simon, Will - [kamer 119 02] Moord in de Stopera
```

Comment: Why don't you require the whitespace surrounding the dash, i.e. `\s+-\s+` instead of `\s*-\s*`? Then it won't match NAME-NAME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex instead:

```
(?:\[[^\]]*\]\s*)?(?P<writer>.*?,.*?)(?:\s+-\s*|\s*-\s+)(?:\[\s*(?P<serie>.+?)\s+(?P<serie_index>\d+)\]\s*)?(?P<title>.*)
```

It considers the dash part of the author's name if there's no whitespace next to the dash.

[regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/cX1tJ4/2)